# check registration custom fields are filed by logged in user woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, registration

In woocommerce customer registration I need to add 2 additional fields (mandatory) year of passing (select box), Name of college (select box).

I need to add these 2 fields to the registration process and prompt existing users to fill them if they try to login.

As in the process will be as follows

1. User tries to login (need to check whether the above fields are filled by user or not - If yes then make him logged in else proceed to step 2)
2. Will get registration page / form to fill in the above additional fields.
3. He will then get logged in to the site.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey I have made changes in the question, please check and let me know if there is anything you need clarifications on.

Comment: I dont want to send an email to the customer, just want to know that is there an option that if the customer login then by a function it should be checked that he needs to fill up some registeration fields so he can be redirected to account edit page with a notification about it. Hope its clear.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: You are welcome… but you should rewrite your question a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done.
As per I understood, you want to add some extra fields to your registration page. Here's how:

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'Full Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" required /></label>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Put the code in function.php and there you go.
It will work perfectly.

Comment: Hey Mate, thanks for the help, I figured out the way to add new fields just want the current users who have already registered to get a prompt to fill in their details before logging in again to the site.